# Can I use a previously set variable for creating the next class member?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to understand better how constructors work in C++. Basically, I would like to know if when initializing the class with a member initializer list in a constructor, everything is set in order.

```cpp
Constructor(int number1, int number2) : 
            m_number1(number1),
            m_number2(m_number1 > 0 ? 0 : number2)
{
}
```

I expect this to be a valid mechanism, however maybe in some special cases it does not work.

Comment: The members will be initialised in the **order they appear in the class definition**. So if you put them in a different order in the initialiser list, you could easily make a mistake here. So you are fine as long as `m_number1` appears **before** `m_number2` in the class.

Comment: If you need to rely on something like that, you might want to rethink your code. I mean, as others stated, there is a certain guaranteed behaviour in this case, but changing it later can create an error very easily. If the order is important and to initialize a member you really need to use another member rather than a parameter, you might want to consider not doing this in the initializer list, even if you know that it will work right now.

Answer (score 1):

The order of non-static member initialisation is determined by the order they appear in the class definition.   This is not related to the order in which those members are listed in a constructor initialiser list.

Your example;

> ```
> Constructor(int number1, int number2) : 
>         m_number1(number1),
>         m_number2(m_number1 > 0 ? 0 : number2)
> {
> }
> ```

will not work as you expect if `m_number2` appears before `m_number1` in the class definition.

Relying on a particular order can be risky if the class definition gets updated - since updates can change the order in which non-static members appear in a class declaration (e.g. if some team member decides that the members are more logically grouped in different ways).

Comment: It's worth noting that compilers generally have warnings for mismatched orders as well.